# Chrome “forgets” search engine integration

Tags: google-chrome, browser, search

When enabling the *Instant Extended API*, Chrome provides a rather nice integration of its search engine into the browser. Supposedly, this means that the Google Search website no longer displays the search text box, along with some other stuff:

[image: screenshot]

(This screenshot is actually outdated, the actual result looked even slimmer.)

After updating to version 30.0.1599.69, this did indeed work for me. However, for whatever reason, the setting silently reverted yesterday. Now I’m once again presented with this:

[image: screenshot]

Since I didn’t change *any* setting in the browser, I’m quite puzzled what might have caused this. I checked under `chrome://flags`, and “Instant Extended API” is still enabled.

This might have something to do with the actual search URI, since it also changes search results: before the revert yesterday, searching for just “weather” would display the current weather at my location. Searching for “restaurants” would show nearby restaurants, etc. Now, searching for either of those terms doesn’t turn up relevant results, just the normal results list.

Here’s my search engine string (needless to say, I also did *not* change it):

```
{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:omniboxStartMarginParameter}ie={inputEncoding}
```

How can I re-enable the search engine integration?

(Other parts that use the Instant Extended API still work, e.g. the History still shows open tabs on my other devices.)

In case it matters, I’m located in the UK. `{google:baseURL}` still seems to resolve to `google.com` rather than `google.co.uk` (see screenshot) but I’m reasonably certain it also did that before.

Comment: I heard Google tests this and that with the Instant Extended API right now, and features are enabled / disabled on one computer to another, even over time. I don't have this nice integration like in your first screenshot. I have some other computers which don't even have the new "New Tab" design.

Comment: A/B testing? This sucks.